# Would a spaceship be able to be stealthy , if it were hidden behind an asteroid in a planetary ring and running on low power?

Tags: space, warfare

Let's say I have a spaceship I want to hide. If the ship had her lights, engine, reactor and non-essential power consuming modules turned off, is covered in a camouflage that reflects light like an asteroid would, and was hidden behind a large asteroid, would it be able to:

- *Keep the crew alive* (half or more of the crew could be kept sleeping through medicines to avoid as much heat generation as possible)
- *Keep her passive sensors on*
- *Stay hidden and/or appear identical to an asteroid when seen from a moderate distance*

Also, I realize this would only make the ship invisible/harder to detect from the opposite side of the asteroid from where she is hidden. The purpose could be to "ambush" potential threats coming to a planet from one specific direction.

Comment: Please could you specify the tech level of the spaceship, its propulsion, etc.?

Comment: Plagiarism is not allowed here.

Comment: @VerNick are you sure it's "plagiarism"? This question was asked 10 hours before the linked duplicate. That alone makes me wonder what you mean by "plagiarism". However, furthermore - the similarity between the names of the two users, the question, both users being new, and this question being migrated, leads me to suspect it's the *same* person who posted the *same* question.

Comment: @vlaz Ver Nick is currently suspended from Movies.SE for plagiarism. I don't know the details, but I'm guessing he's a bit upset about it.

Comment: @F1Krazy I see. I guess that sheds some light on the comment.

Comment: @F1Krazy [That's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96502/why-was-peter-parkers-passport-censored-in-the-trailer/96534#comment163274_96534) why I was suspended, though I didn't mention the source only twice. I'm not upset, just a bit surprised.